Data is not saved in Flipkart script in python
I am working on a Python script to fetch product prices using Selenium.
However, I am encountering a timeout error when using EC.presence_of_element_located.  Here’s the relevant portion of
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.VU-ZEz, ._30jeq3')))   

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:  I believe the issue is that the Chrome browser crashes unexpectedly when the script is executed. Could you please guide me on alternative ways to resolve this problem?
ERROR
2024-12-06 07:40:02,553 - INFO - {'success': True, 'message': 'Affiliate Link Retrieved Successfully', 'data': [{'id': '917', 'url': 'https://fkrt.co/nBKuEP', 'type': 1}], 'status_code': 200}
2024-12-06 07:40:04,188 - INFO - ====== WebDriver manager ======
2024-12-06 07:40:04,311 - INFO - Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome
2024-12-06 07:40:04,377 - INFO - Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome
2024-12-06 07:40:04,436 - INFO - Driver [/home/rijbggmy/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/131.0.6778.87/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver] found in cache
{'success': True, 'message': 'Affiliate Link Retrieved Successfully', 'data': [{'id': '917', 'url': 'https://fkrt.co/nBKuEP', 'type': 1}], 'status_code': 200}
/home/rijbggmy/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/131.0.6778.87/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver
/home/rijbggmy/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/131.0.6778.87/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rijbggmy/public_html/vvosm/flipkart.py", line 525, in <module>
    flipkart_product_info = fetch_price_using_selenium(url, version)
  File "/home/rijbggmy/public_html/vvosm/flipkart.py", line 247, in fetch_price_using_selenium
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 238, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 325, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 380, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from unknown error: cannot parse internal JSON template: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55cff296934a <unknown>
#1 0x55cff247f6e0 <unknown>
#2 0x55cff24bb2a2 <unknown>
#3 0x55cff24bb7c1 <unknown>
#4 0x55cff24b5288 <unknown>
#5 0x55cff24b2926 <unknown>
#6 0x55cff24fe6f6 <unknown>
#7 0x55cff24fdd46 <unknown>
#8 0x55cff24f2203 <unknown>
#9 0x55cff24c0cc0 <unknown>
#10 0x55cff24c1c9e <unknown>
#11 0x55cff2936d3b <unknown>
#12 0x55cff293acc2 <unknown>
#13 0x55cff2923b6c <unknown>
#14 0x55cff293b837 <unknown>
#15 0x55cff290910f <unknown>
#16 0x55cff29585a8 <unknown>
#17 0x55cff2958770 <unknown>
#18 0x55cff29681c6 <unknown>
#19 0x7f97d0889d22 start_thread

My script is as follows.
import logging
import pymysql
import re
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from pymysql.err import OperationalError
from unshortenit import UnshortenIt
import os
import subprocess
import platform
import glob
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

class FlipkartProductInfo:
    title           = None
    productId       = None
    originalPrice   = None
    offerPrice      = None
    discount        = None
    url             = None
    categories      = None
    description     = None
    brandName       = None
    rating          = None
    totalRatings    = None
    imageUrl        = None

telegram_chat_id    = '*********'
unshortener         = UnshortenIt()

DB_CONFIG = {
    'user'          : '**********',
    'password'      : '**********',
    'host'          : '127.0.0.1',
    'database'      : '**********',
    'charset'       : 'utf8mb4',
    'cursorclass'   : pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
}

api_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/{method}'.format

def telegram_command(name, data):
    url     = api_url(token="**********:***********-******************", method=name)
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    return requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=data)

def telegram_sendMessage(text: str, chat_id: str, notify=False):
    return telegram_command('sendMessage', {
        'text'                      : text,
        'chat_id'                   : chat_id,
        'parse_mode'                : 'markdown',
        'disable_web_page_preview'  : True,
        'disable_notification'      : not notify
    })

def get_chromedriver_version():
    try:
        system_platform = platform.system()

        if system_platform == "Linux":
            # Base path where ChromeDriver versions are stored
            base_dir = "/home/rijbggmy/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/"
            
            # Use glob to find all version directories
            version_dirs = glob.glob(os.path.join(base_dir, "*/"))
            
            if not version_dirs:
                return "No ChromeDriver versions found."

            # Identify the latest version directory
            latest_version_dir = max(version_dirs, key=os.path.getmtime)
            chromedriver_path = os.path.join(latest_version_dir, "chromedriver-linux64", "chromedriver")
            print(chromedriver_path)

            if os.path.exists(chromedriver_path):
                # Extract version using the ChromeDriver binary
                result = subprocess.run([chromedriver_path, "--version"], capture_output=True, text=True)
                version = re.search(r"ChromeDriver (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)", result.stdout)
                return version.group(1) if version else "Unable to parse ChromeDriver version."
            else:
                return f"ChromeDriver binary not found at {chromedriver_path}"
        else:
            return "ChromeDriver is only supported on Linux in this function."

    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error fetching ChromeDriver version: {e}"

def fetch_price_using_selenium(url, version):
    """Fetch product details using Selenium."""
    options = Options()
    user_data_dir = f"/home/rijbggmy/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/{version}/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver"
    print(user_data_dir)
    options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir='{user_data_dir}'")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1,1")
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    try:
        flipkart_product_info = FlipkartProductInfo()
        flipkart_product_info.url = url

        # Unshorten the URL before using it
        unshortened_url = unshorten_url(url)
        driver.get(unshortened_url)

        # Adjusted wait strategy
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.VU-ZEz, ._30jeq3')))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        flipkart_product_info.title = (soup.find('span', class_='VU-ZEz').text.strip()
                                       if soup.find('span', class_='VU-ZEz') else 'N/A')

        # Extract product information using helper functions
        flipkart_product_info.offerPrice        = getOfferPrice(soup)
        flipkart_product_info.originalPrice     = getOriginalPrice(soup)
        flipkart_product_info.discount          = getDiscount(soup)
        flipkart_product_info.description       = getDescription(soup)
        flipkart_product_info.rating            = getRatings(soup)
        flipkart_product_info.totalRatings      = getTotalRatings(soup)
        flipkart_product_info.categories        = getCategories(soup)
        flipkart_product_info.imageUrl          = getImageURLs(soup)
        flipkart_product_info.brandName         = getBrandName(soup)

        # Extract product ID from the unshortened URL
        # flipkart_product_info.productId = get_flipkart_product_id(unshortened_url)
        flipkart_product_info.productId = generate_flipkart_product_id(url)

        if not flipkart_product_info.productId:
            raise ValueError(f"Product ID is missing for URL: {url}")

    except Exception as err:
        logging.error("An error occurred:")
        logging.exception(err)
        telegram_sendMessage(str(err), telegram_chat_id)
    finally:
        driver.quit()

    return flipkart_product_info

def save_product_to_database(flipkart_product_info, store_id, affiliate_link_id, soup, old_image_url=None):
    """Save product and image details to the database."""
    # if not flipkart_product_info.productId:
    #     logging.error("Cannot save product with missing product_id. Skipping...")
    #     return

    connection = None
    cursor = None
    description = None
    try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(**DB_CONFIG)
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        slug = generate_slug(flipkart_product_info.title or 'Unknown Product')
        current_time = datetime.now()
        soldBy = 'flipkart'
        
        productId = generate_flipkart_product_id(url)

        # Get the description
        description = getDescription(soup)
        print(description)

        # Set isActive based on whether a description was found
        isActive = '1' if description else '0'

        # Updated SQL query to include all extracted fields
        insert_query = """
        INSERT INTO products (product_id, slug, title, actual_price, selling_price, discount, affiliate_link, description, sold_by, store_id, is_active, created_at)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        """
        record = (
            productId,
            slug,
            flipkart_product_info.title,
            flipkart_product_info.originalPrice,
            flipkart_product_info.offerPrice,
            flipkart_product_info.discount,
            flipkart_product_info.url,
            description,  # Use the fetched description here
            soldBy,
            store_id,
            isActive,
            current_time
        )

        cursor.execute(insert_query, record)
        connection.commit()

        imageble_id = cursor.lastrowid

        if old_image_url:
            delete_image_query = "DELETE FROM images WHERE file_path = %s"
            cursor.execute(delete_image_query, (old_image_url,))
            logging.info(f"Deleted old image: {old_image_url}")

        if flipkart_product_info.imageUrl:
            for image_url in flipkart_product_info.imageUrl:
                local_image_path = download_image(image_url)
                if local_image_path:
                    insert_image_query = """
                    INSERT INTO images (imageble_type, imageble_id, file_path, created_at, updated_at)
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                    """
                    image_record = ('App\\Models\\Product', imageble_id, local_image_path, current_time, current_time)
                    cursor.execute(insert_image_query, image_record)

        connection.commit()
        logging.info("Product and image data saved to the database successfully.")

        # After saving the product, save the categories, passing the imageble_id
        if flipkart_product_info.categories:
            save_categories_to_database(flipkart_product_info.categories, imageble_id)  # Pass the product ID here

        # Update the affiliate_links table
        update_affiliate_query = """
            UPDATE affiliate_links SET is_fetch = %s, updated_at = %s WHERE id = %s
            """
        current_time = datetime.now()  # Assuming you want to set the updated timestamp
        cursor.execute(update_affiliate_query, ('1', current_time, affiliate_link_id))
        connection.commit()

        product_details = format_product_details(flipkart_product_info)
        telegram_sendMessage(product_details, telegram_chat_id)

    except OperationalError as e:
        logging.error(f"Error while connecting to MySQL: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if connection:
            connection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    api_endpoint = "http://rij.bgg.mybluehostin.me/vvosm/api/flipkart/get-url"

    response = requests.get(api_endpoint)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        print(data)
        logging.info(data)

        # Extract URLs and storeId from the API response
        for item in data.get("data", []):
            url                 = item["url"]
            store_id            = item.get("type")
            affiliate_link_id   = item["id"]

            # Create the soup object from the fetched URL
            response = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
            
            version = get_chromedriver_version()
            if not version:
                logging.error("Failed to fetch Chrome version.")
                continue

            flipkart_product_info = fetch_price_using_selenium(url, version)
            save_product_to_database(flipkart_product_info, store_id=store_id, affiliate_link_id=affiliate_link_id, soup=soup)
    else:
        logging.error("API request failed")


I think selenium allows adding a timeout. You can try to increase the timeout and explicitly specify it. Take a look at these examples: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk/examples/python/tests/drivers/test_options.py#L9
